# Call function with custom type parameter with reflection VB.NET

Tags: .net, system.reflection

I have a main program that is loading dll plugins with System.Reflection.

There is simple custom class:

```
Public Class SProperty
    Public PropertyType As SPropertyType
    Public Value As String
    Public BaseAddress As String
    Public Lenght As Long
    Public Name As String
    Public UpsertKey As Boolean
End Class
```

That is defined in main program as well as in plugin library.

There is method in plugin library:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByRef Props as List(Of SProperty))
    ...
End Sub
```

If I call the method from main program, then error occurs - it is in another language - I will try to translate that: SProperty cannot be converted to SProperty.

I tried to load type from the plugin library, but it is difficult because of List(Of ) and I was not successfull.

Is there any chance to make that type convertible or universal for both the main program and plugin?

Please can you advise the right way?

Best Regards,
Jan

Comment: *"That is defined in main program as well as in plugin library."*  - Don't do that.  If you declare a new class with the same name as the one in the library **they are not the same class** and are not compatible.  One will be `MyNamespace.SProperty` and the other will be `LibraryNamespace.SProperty` and they are as different as if you had named your class anything else.  Don't redefine the class - just use the one defined in the library.

Comment: I tried to load the type from plugin library, but I was unable to use it in the List(Of ) type. It seems that Im missing something. Or you mean I can create one library with that class and use it in main program as well as in plugin library? Will it work?

Comment: @J... I cut the definition of that object to another class and reference it in both projects and it seems to be working! Thank you!